# Get value of a particular column from a SQL stored procedure which returns table

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure lets say its name is `SP1`, and it returns a table. Now I have another stored procedure `SP2`.

What I am want to do something like this inside `SP2`:

```
set @SP2_var = SP1.column_name
```

so that the `@SP2_var` can access the value. The table returned by `SP1` is a temporary table like `Select * from #temp`.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetConditionDataByRouteId]
    @RouteId INT
AS
    DECLARE @obj sys.Geography
    DECLARE @reportedDate DateTime
    Select @obj= CachedRoute From Route where Id=@RouteId
    SELECT * INTO #temp FROM (SELECT * FROM PavementRawDataTable Where BeginGeo.STDistance(@obj)<=5 and AgencyId=dbo.GetAgencyId(@RouteId)) as X
    SELECT Top 1 @reportedDate= SurveyDateTime FROM [#temp] 
    SELECT 
      Avg([RQI]) RQI,
      (SELECT RQIOver FROM PF_Condition WHERE SegmentId=@RouteId) RQIOver,
      Avg([SR]) SR,
      (SELECT SROver FROM PF_Condition WHERE SegmentId=@RouteId) SROver,
      Avg([PQI]) PQI,
      (SELECT PQIOver FROM PF_Condition WHERE SegmentId=@RouteId) PQIOver,
      Avg([IRIAvg]) IRI,
      (SELECT IRIOver FROM PF_Condition WHERE SegmentId=@RouteId) IRIOver,
      NULL PCI,
      (SELECT PCIOver FROM PF_Condition WHERE SegmentId=@RouteId) PCIOver,
      Avg([RutAvg]) Rut,
      (SELECT RUTOver FROM PF_Condition WHERE SegmentId=@RouteId) RUTOver,
      dbo.GetPlannedProjectYear(@RouteId) PlannedProjYear ,
      (SELECT PlannedProjectYearOver FROM PF_Condition WHERE SegmentId=@RouteId) PlannedProjectYearOver,
      dbo.GetPlannedProjectType(@RouteId) PlannedProjType,
      (SELECT PlannedProjectTypeOver FROM PF_Condition WHERE SegmentId=@RouteId) PlannedProjectTypeOver,
      @reportedDate CollectedDate,
      (SELECT DateCollectedOver FROM PF_Condition WHERE SegmentId=@RouteId) DateCollectedOver

  FROM [#temp]  
 END
```

This is SP1. And I want to store the value PQI from this stored procedure to a variable in SP2.

Any help is really appreciated. Thanks

Comment: If it's returning a table, what are you expecting to assign as the value of `column_name` (which will have multiple values) to a single Scalar Variable?

Comment: Nope - stored procedure returns a resultset, not a table. Erland discusses several options [here](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html)

Comment: I will post the SP1 so that it gives a better understanding what the stored procedure is returning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of the `INSERT/EXEC` approach applied to your queries.

```
-- You'll need to define the data types being returned in the result set
DECLARE @Results TABLE (
    RQI DECIMAL,
    RQIOver DECIMAL,
    SR DECIMAL,
    SROver DECIMAL,
    PQI DECIMAL,
    PQIOver DECIMAL,
    IRI DECIMAL,
    IRIOver DECIMAL,
    PCI DECIMAL,
    PCIOver DECIMAL,
    Rut DECIMAL,
    RUTOver DECIMAL,
    PlannedProjYear DECIMAL,
    PlannedProjectYearOver DECIMAL,
    PlannedProjectTypeOver DECIMAL,
    CollectedDate DATETIME,
    DateCollectedOver DATETIME
)
-- Call SP (assumes you already have @RouteId defined)
INSERT @Results
    EXEC [dbo].[GetConditionDataByRouteId] @RouteId

-- Now you can refer to SP1 column from result set
SET @SP2_var = (SELECT TOP 1 RQI FROM @Results)
```

**UPDATE**

If you wanted to share the temp table, then it would have to be created in the calling stored procedure. For example:

```
CREATE PROC SP1
AS BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    UPDATE #temp SET A = 2
END
GO

CREATE PROC SP2
AS BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    SELECT 1 AS A INTO #temp
    EXEC SP1
    SELECT * FROM #temp -- This is now "2"
END
GO
```

Here `SP2` stored proc creates the temp table, so when it calls `SP1`, then `SP1` can see and update it.

This can be risky since `SP1` has to assume the caller has created the temp table it is expecting to exist. `INSERT/EXEC` may be a cleaner and safer implementation for many cases.

Comment: Ok. That was my confusion. So I have to declare the result table seperately again in SP2 else I wont be able to access the value. I thought if it is possible since I am calling SP1 in SP2 so I can access #temp table of SP1 directly. Thank you.

Comment: The #temp tables are only available from the stored procedure it is created (#SP1). If you created the table in #SP2, then #SP1 would be able to see it and update it. I'll post an example in the answer.

Comment: you could also create a [custom table type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-type-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#c-creating-a-user-defined-table-type) to reuse across multiple stored procedures

Comment: Yes, a custom table type would prevent the need of defining the table variable structure in each calling stored proc. However, you cannot use it as an `OUTPUT` parameter unless it is also `READONLY`, so it cannot be used as a parameter into the called stored procedure.